# Determine Next Pay Date Based On Today's Date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My employer pays every two weeks on a Friday.

Let's say the start date was April 14.

Following pay days are:
April 28
May 12
May 26 and so on...

I want to be able to insert the next pay day in datetime format for a database, relative to CURDATE().

**Example:**
If the code is run on May 22, the entry would be 2017-05-26 00:00:00

If the code is run on June 1, the entry would be 2017-06-09 00:00:00

If the code is run on the same day as the pay day it would revert to the next pay day.

**Same Day Example:**
If the code is run on June 9, the entry would be 2017-06-23 00:00:00

**What I've Tried:**

**UPDATE**

```
$StartDate = strtotime('2017-05-12'); //Start date from which we begin count
$CurDate = date("Y-m-d"); //Current date.
$NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $StartDate)); //Next date = +2 week from start date
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($CurDate . "+1 days"));

if($CurDate == $NextDate){$CurDate = $tomorrow;}
while ($CurDate > $NextDate ) { 
  $NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($NextDate)));
}

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($NextDate)), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next Friday from today (even if today is a Friday):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next friday'));
```

To get the next Friday from a date:

```
$start = strtotime('April 14');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next friday', $start));
```

To get the next Friday plus one week:

```
$start = strtotime('April 14');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next friday +1 week', $start));
```

There are many possibilities, or check the [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, the only that yo need is store in database the last payment date, and calculate the next based on this, then don't matter when the code is executed, the next payment date is calculated based on latest payment date:

```
$nextPayDay = (clone $lastPayDay)->modify('Friday + 2 weeks');
```

if the code run the same day of payment, ensure update `$lastPayDay` with current date.